# Matrix expression for elements of $\text{SO}_0(1,4)$

Tags: lie-groups, spin-geometry, quaternions

Denote by $\text{SO}_0(1,4)$ the identity component of the special linear isometry group $\mathrm{SO}(1,4)$ of the Lorentz-Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}_1^5$, that is, of
$$\text{SO}(1,4)=\left\{X\in\text{SL}(5,\mathbb{R})\mid X^tI_{1,4}X=I_{1,4}\right\},\quad\text{where}\;I_{1,4}:=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1,1).$$
Is there any explicit matrix expression for a general element of this Lie group?
Maybe using quaternions or spin representation?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition help...?

Comment: I'm not so sure what the question is. Iwasawa decomposition provides one particular parameterization, is it what's meant by "matrix expression"?

Comment: Wrong equality $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)=\mathrm O(1,4)\cap\mathrm{SL}(5,\mathbf R)$ now corrected. (RHS still has *two* components.)

Comment: Francois is right. Indeed, $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)$ is not Zariski-closed in $\mathrm{GL}_5(\mathbf{R})$ and hence cannot be the intersection of two Zariski-closed subgroups.

Comment: There is also the 2-to-1 parametrization by $SL_2(\mathbb H)$, with Hamiltonian quaternions.

Comment: @paulgarrett $SL_2(H)$ is isogeneous to $SO(5,1)$, not $SO(4,1)$ (check the dimension!... actually I found the same error in Witte's book too).

Comment: The question is vague and the answer, of course, depends on the intended use of this parametrization.  In addition to the Cartan and Iwasawa decompositions mentioned by others, there are also the exponential map and the Cayley transform (both parametrize suitably defined *generic* elements forming a dense subset of the group in terms of the Lie algebra).

Comment: @VictorProtsak The question intended to be broad because I didn't even know if there was something else, apart from the Iwasawa decomposition, that could be considered as a *parametrization* of this Lie group, but I am aware that this broadness can be also seen as a problem, sorry in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cartan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition#Cartan_decomposition_on_the_Lie_group_level):
$$
\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)=\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
1&0\\\hline
0&A
\end{array}\right)
\exp\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
0&{}^tb\\\hline
b&0
\end{array}\right): A\in\mathrm{SO}(4), b\in\mathbf R^{4\times1}
\right\},
$$
(where the exponential is easily computed explicitly in terms of hyperbolic sines and cosines) boils this down to your favorite parametrization of [$\mathrm{SO}(4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space).

Comment: I think this was what I was looking for. I'll work on this decomposition to see if it works for me.

Comment: (The computed exponential is in e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0156, (30) and (35).)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there should be an explicit expression. Let me sketch how to get it. Start with the [Iwasawa decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition) to write your matrix $M$ as a product of three matrices $M = KAN$ where $N$ is nilpotent, $A$ is abelian and $K$ is a matrix from the maximal compact subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)$ which is $\mathrm{S}(\mathrm{O(1)} \times \mathrm{O}(4))_0 \simeq \mathrm{SO}(4).$ Now the elements of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ can be parametrized by two-tuples of [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Relation_to_quaternions). The explicit form of these matrices depends on your symmetric form as was kindly noted by YCor in the comments.

Comment: There's already one problem: the maximal split torus of $SO(4,1)$, for the given choice of representation (i.e., the choice of $I_{1,4}$), cannot be chosen in diagonal form (and $N$ doesn't take an upper triangular form either).

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. I'm so used to antidiagonal forms for orthogonal groups that I always assume them. I'll edit.

Comment: The maximal compact subgroup of a connected Lie group is connected. In your case it will just be $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ (the maximal compact in $\mathrm{SO}(1,4)$ is $\mathrm{S}(\mathrm{O}(1)\times\mathrm{O}(4))$).

Comment: @YCor Thank you. I've overlooked the zero index.

Comment: @YCor If I consider the symmetric space $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)/(\mathrm{SO}_0(1,3)\times \mathrm{SO}(1))$ defined by the involution $\sigma:\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)\to\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)$, given by $\sigma(X) = DXD^{-1}$, with $D = \text{diag}\left\{-1,-1,-1,-1,1\right\}$, then by Cartan decomposition I get the subgroup $K$ of $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{k}$ which should be the maximal subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,4)$. Isn't this $K$ just $\mathrm{SO}_0(1,3)\times \mathrm{SO}(1)$?

Comment: It's not a symmetric space, at least in the usual sense. Maybe it's a pseudo-Riemannian symmetric space in some reasonable sense. Don't know what you mean by "the maximal subgroup". Notation $K$ evokes a compact group but $SO(1,3)$ is certainly not compact.

Comment: @YCor Yes, you're right, it is just a pseudo-Riemannian symmetric space.